# How to 'balance' a set a maximal lengths?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I have a given total length $T$ in a given location. I have a function that calculates a set of contiguous sub-lengths ($l$) along the total length, from one end to the other. Each sub-length is the maximum length it can be in that location.

So I end up with $l_n$ maximal lengths and a remainder $R$ that sum to the total $T$. This should give me the minimum possible number of sub-lengths (i.e., $n+1$)

I'm trying to figure out a sensible way to balance $l$ towards its average value, such that $R$ is also closer to the average (I say average, but since that is a moving target, I really mean 'make the lengths in $l$ more similar'). However:

- the values in $l$ can be very dissimilar, meaning (potentially) some are much shorter than the average, some much longer.
- but each value in $l$ is maximal for its (start) position, meaning I can only make them shorter.
- and they are (and should be) contiguous, if I make $l_x$ shorter I need to make $l_{x+1}$ longer, or recalculate the max length of $l_{x+1}$ (and then every subsequent length too).
- I don't want any more than $n+1$ sub-lengths if I can help it

So I'm thinking something iterative like:

- move through $l$ until I find a length longer than the average
- shorten that length toward the average
- recalculate the remaining max lengths
- repeat until whatever measure of 'balanced' I decide upon is met

Is there a better (more mathematical?) way?

**EDIT for clarification:**

It's probably clear, but I'm not a mathematician, so I don't know - or understand! - the correct terminology but...

My primary line is an elevation profile, the changing gradient of which (in part) dictates the maximal sub-lengths. But perhaps it is sufficient to say that from any starting point on the primary line, moving forward toward the other end of the line, conditions dictate a maximal sub-length. Change the starting point and you change the maximal sub-length.

The objective function is a somewhat nebulous heuristic one (if you ask the people concerned), but mathematically, I want to make all the sub-lengths as similar in length as possible while minimising the number of sublengths (I think!)

**EDIT for example:**

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|} \hline
\mathbf{Sublength} & \mathbf{Value} \\ \hline
A & 50\\ \hline \hline
B & 34\\ \hline
C & 44\\ \hline
D & 40\\ \hline
E & 78\\ \hline
F & 119\\ \hline
G & 71\\ \hline
H & 60\\ \hline
I & 170\\ \hline
J & 99\\ \hline
K & 22.93\\ \hline
\mathbf{Total:} & 787.93\\ \hline
\mathbf{Mean:} & 71.63.93\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
So in this example $A$-$D$ cannot be changed, as they are shorter than the mean. I could significantly shorten $F$, but would then have to recalculate $G$-$K$ and re-evaluate, thus leading to some sort of iterative rippling effect?

Comment: Why would there be a remainder R if all of the "sublengths" are "as big as they can be"?  I mean, this post makes very little sense on the whole, but that in particular seems like a place you can start clarifying.

Comment: I actually see the hint of an interesting question here, though I am very unsure that I read what you wrote correctly.  Are you saying you have an interval of real numbers $ I $ and you are given a function $ f : I \rightarrow \mathcal{I} $ (where $ \mathcal{I} $ is the set of all subintervals of $ I $) with $ x \in f(x) $ for all $ x \in I $?  And you're trying to pick a finite subcollection $ A = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \} $ which optimizes some objective?  Am I right, and if so, what is the objective?  And what do we know about the function $ f $.

Comment: Jake - my function produces a maximum (sub)length based on where I start and other conditions along the line. For example, if I start at distance 0 along the primary line conditions would dictate that my first maximal sub length is $a$. I'd then continue from $a$ and find the next maximal sub length $b$ etc. However, were I to start a distance 2, my first maximal sub-length (and thus subsequent ones also) would be different.

Comment: A numerical example would he helpful here.

Comment: Mathematicians are great at solving problems and ones like myself would be eager to help you with your problem.  However, without a *well-defined* problem, no one can help you unless they guess your objective for you.  What you need to do, more than exploring computer programs and algorithms, is to take time to come up with a rigorous statement of your problems so that other people understand your goals and constraints.  Focus on goals and constraints: what specifically you want, and what specifically you are allowed (and are not allowed) to do to achieve it.

Comment: Since you indicated that you don't want "too many" intervals, and you want them to be "roughly the same length", let's define an objective function $ g(\{I_i\}) $ defined all collection of intervals.  Let's define it to be $ g(\{I_i\}) = \alpha \sigma + n $ where $ \alpha $ is some positive constant you can experiment with, $ \sigma $ is the standard deviation of the lengths, and $ n $ is the number of intervals used.  Then we can say that your *objective* is to minimize $ g(\{I_i\}) $.  You would still need to clarify your constraints.  Which interval collections are permissible?